# New sections do not show up in my UITableView after the first new section (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This may be a little complex. I am adding rows into a UITableView based off of events that I create. Each event has a start time. I use this start time to create sections.

To illustrate, if I have three events: one starting at 8:00am, one starting at 12:00pm, and the third starting at 8:00am, then the first and third event will show up as two elements of the section with the header 8:00am, and the second event will show up as an element of the section with the header 12:00pm.

I have a section list `var sectionList = Dictionary<Int, [Event]>()`
which takes in the starting time of the event as the key (Int), and the array of events that start at that time as the item. With my example, my dictionary would be `{800: [event1, event3], 1200: [event2]}`

To have these in the right sorted order, I created an array `sortedKeys = Array(sectionList.keys).sorted(<)`

After an Event item is created in the app, my viewWillAppear method is called: 
`override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        getSortedSectionList()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }`
Which creates a new sorted section list and sorted keys list before reloading my UITableView data.

This works for the creation of the first event at 8:00am. Unfortunately, when I create the second event, neither the event nor the item shows up in my list. However, when I add the third event, it is placed in the same section as the first event, and is visible.

Why isn't the second section appearing and how can I make it appear?

Comment: Have you implemented the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` delegate method?

Comment: Surprisingly, no. :/ I'm going to try now

Comment: Thank you for reading my whole novel! haha It works :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dummy, you forgot to implement numberOfSectionsInTableView!

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if sortedKeys.count > 0 {
        return sortedKeys.count
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}
```